# The dependency `Mixpanel` is not used in any concrete target

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, react-native

I'm trying to add mixpanel plugin into my react-native project.
I'm using these links

[react-native-mix panel github](https://github.com/davodesign84/react-native-mixpanel)

and the integration in xcode is here
[mixpanel cocoapods](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ios)

I followed these instructions:

1. Install CocoaPods using gem install cocoapods
2. If this is your first time using CocoaPods, run pod setup to create a local CocoaPods spec mirror.
3. Create a file in your Xcode project called Podfile and add the following line: pod 'Mixpanel'
4. Run pod install in your Xcode project directory. CocoaPods should download and install the Mixpanel library, and create a new
   Xcode workspace. Open up this workspace in Xcode.

> gem install cocoapods

then I run pod setup and create Podfile text file into the project.
then when I run pod install into my bash command line i get this error

> The dependency `Mixpanel` is not used in any concrete target.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to run `pod init` from your react native `ios` directory. This generates the correct starting podfile, targeting your app correctly.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7775

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the above error.
So I added the Text file in podfile in below format:

```
target "MercadoPagoSample" do

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
# Se necesita este parámetro por ser una SDK en swift
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'MercadoPagoSDK', '3.6.0'
end
```

Then I was able to update the podfile.